# mongoDB backup/restore from batch file using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, batch-file

Here is my java code to execute batch file to restore mongo database. It is taking forever (kept running for 25 minutes and did not stop yet). When i restore only single collection then it works fine the issue is when i restore full database.

Thank You in Advance.

```
Process pDb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c restore_db.bat",null, new File(projectPath));

try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pDb.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
        }
}

log.info("waiting for restore complete database...");

int exitVal = pDb.waitFor();

log.info("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Here is my code of restore_db.bat batch file.

```
@echo off

REM move into the backups directory
CD C:\project\backup

REM restore the database
echo Running restore complete database
mongorestore --db dbName dump/app

echo RESTORE COMPLETE
```

Comment: when you restore manually what amount of time is needed to finish?

Comment: It takes 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: ok, thanks for answer - did you run just batch file? How long does it take?

Comment: Yes i run batch file. The batch file takes time in this line.     mongorestore --db dbName dump/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) i managed to solve my issue. I changed my java code to this

```
Process pDb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c restore_db.bat",null, new File(projectPath));

InputStream stderr = pDb.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);

try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String line;

            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
            }
}

log.info("waiting for restore complete database...");

exitVal = pDb.waitFor();

log.info("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Then i get the actual reason of hanging of the process. I java console i am getting this error: E11000 duplicate key error index. Which is in the batch file i am restoring the same database. When i changed the name of database in batch file then the database is restored in no time.
i.e

```
mongorestore --db dbName dump/app
```

changed to

```
mongorestore --db dbName2 dump/app
```

then new database with name dbName2 is restored .